# XORing least significant bits in java

Tags: java

I've read a ton about bitwise arithmetic in Java but I always seem to somehow get it wrong. I'm trying to figure out how to XOR the two least significant bits in two bytes of java.

Example:

byteOne = 01010101
byteTwo = 11111111
byteOne becomes 01010100 due to the least significant bit in byteTwo

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
byteOne ^= byteTwo & 1;
```

Comment: Whoops, you got there a few seconds before me.  I'll delete mine.

Comment: thanks! it seems simple but I always find a way to mess it up

Answer (score 2):

[I once wrote an applet for bitmanipulation](http://home.arcor.de/hirnstrom/minis/index.html#bitorgel) which you might find interesting to play with.