# replacing Least Significant bits

Tags: java, binary

i want to replace Least significant bits with the given array...

1st input

```
01001100
00001000
10101010
01010100
11110110
```

2nd input

```
0
1
1
1
0
```

output

```
01001100
00001001
10101011
01010101
11110110
```

Comment: i am not getting any logic i tried a lot,

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359495/xoring-least-significant-bits-in-java

Comment: Is the input String of arrays?

Comment: Could you add whatever you tried to the question? Thanks.

Comment: 1st array of String of binary pixels 2nd array of byte, i want to replace each Least significant bit of 1st array ie array of binary pixel from bits of 2nd array

Comment: You will input the Binary string representing a decimal number instead of actual Decimal Number.? If thats true then it's just not a big deal to solve this.

Comment: You can't specify this by example. Try to define a rule. Then the translation into code should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

try this (using java 7)

```
   int [] i = {0b01001100,
           0b00001000,
           0b10101010,
           0b01010100,
           0b11110110 };
   int [] j = {0b0,
           0b1,
           0b1,
           0b1,
           0b0 };

   for (int k = 0; k < i.length ; ++k){
       i[k] = (i[k] >> 1) << 1;  // this sets the last bit to zero
       i[k] = i[k] | j[k];       // Now you can OR to get replace with the proper value 
   }

   for(int k : i)
       System.out.printf("%8s\n",Integer.toBinaryString(k));
   System.out.println("----------");
```

Comment: it is not possible, coz both arrays are user input and after a lot processing it is generated

Comment: @user1939093 This answers your question. It's another matter how the arrays are finally formed.

Comment: @user1939093 there was an error in my earlier code. I have fixed it.